# Append array to array in PHP and then print the contents

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

How would I go about creating a dictionary with values set to arrays in PHP?

Here's my pseudo:

```
$items = array();
array_push($items, $itemone => array("one", "two"));
array_push($items, $itemtwo => array("three", "four"));
array_push($items, $itemone => array("five", "six")); #overwrites existing

print $items[$itemone[0]] # prints five
print $items[$itemtwo[1]] # prints four
```

Comment: Would you prefer to call the items by keyname? like this: $items['itemone']

Comment: That would be excellent! lol, but I'd still need to be able to access array values by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$items = array();

$items[] = array('one', 'two');
$items[] = array('three', 'four');
$items[] = array('five', 'six');
```

Using the [] syntax acts like a push but does not incur the overhead of a function call, see the PHP doc.

You can access $items[0], $items[1], etc...

```
echo $items[0][1]; // prints two
```

The array would look like:

```
[ ['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six'] ]
```

If for some reason, you want to use associative keys you could do this:

```
$items = array();

$items['item-one'] = array('one', 'two');
$items['item-two'] = array('three', 'four');
$items['item-three'] = array('five', 'six');
```

Then the array would look like this:

```
[ 'item-one' => ['one', 'two'], 'item-two' => ['three', 'four'], 'item-three' => ['five', 'six'] ]
```

If I wanted to print three, then I'd do this:

```
echo $items['item-two'][0]; // prints three
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks very much. Is it possible to call them by keyname, however? That would save an extra level of recursion